# 503 error Varnish cache when eAccelerator is started

Tags: apache-2.2, cache, varnish, performance-tuning, php

I have a Magento installation running on x-large Amazon server. I have Varnish, memcached and eAccelerator installed on the server. At first everything was working fine, but then at some point it stopped working, throwing 503 error with Varnish cache stamp below it. When I disable eaccelerator, error is gone and site is working. This is my eaccelerator config:

`extension="eaccelerator.so"

eaccelerator.shm_size = "512"

eaccelerator.cache_dir = "/var/cache/php-eaccelerator"

eaccelerator.enable = "1"

eaccelerator.optimizer = "1"

eaccelerator.debug = 0

eaccelerator.log_file = "/var/log/httpd/eaccelerator_log"

eaccelerator.name_space = ""

eaccelerator.check_mtime = "1"

eaccelerator.filter = ""

eaccelerator.shm_ttl = "0"

eaccelerator.shm_prune_period = "0"

eaccelerator.shm_only = "0"

eaccelerator.allowed_admin_path = ""`

any hints?

Comment: Is it Varnish throwing the 503, or the application?

Comment: I think it's Varnish. Application is unreachable, as phpinfo() file is also unavailable

Comment: Can you try to issue a request directly to Apache without going through Varnish?

Comment: I don't know how to do that :/

Comment: If your Apache listens to port 8080, try go to http://www.example.org:8080/phpinfo.php instead of http://www.example.org/phpinfo.php. Correct domain and paths for your site.

Comment: 8080 not responding, 80 throws 503 `Apache/2.2.21 (Fedora) Server at *** Port 80 `

Comment: Find out what port your Apache is listening on, then try to send a request to that port. If apache listens on 8080, but it's currently down, it might explain your 503s.

Comment: when I try to restart apache, I get "httpd not running, attempting to start".. so apache is probably down.. any idea why? Maybe port collision of some sort?

Comment: Maybe. Check if you can find your Apache logs and see if you find anything related in the errorlog.

Comment: well that helped. I was trying to allocate more memory than was allowed in kernel `/proc/sys/kernel/shmmax`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was caused by the fact that kernel allowed only 32M of shared memory, as defined in `/proc/sys/kernel/shmmax` , while I was trying to allocate 512M.